# Angular.js. Ng-model of checkbox

Tags: angularjs

Here's my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="variable">
```

In this case `variable` will be `true` or `false` according the status of checkbox. I need to set not `true`/`false` but `"+"`/`"-"` instead. What is the simplest way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D), you should use `ng-true-value` and/or `ng-false-value` to override `true` and `false` values:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="variable" ng-true-value="+" ng-false-value="-">
```

Answer (score 3):

Use ng-click to do that.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="variable" ng-click="check()">
```

In the controller :

```
$scope.check = function() {
    $scope.selected = $scope.variable === true ? '+' : '-';
};
```

[Live Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/AUkZwWKuVRCL8j5611ye?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Just setup a watch on your checkbox model.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked">
```

JavaScript:

```
// set initial value
$scope.isChecked = $scope.variable === '+';

// watch for changes to the checkbox model
$scope.$watch('isChecked', function(newVal) {
    $scope.variable = newVal ? '+' : '-';
};
```

Comment: Just a reminder: You don't need to set initial value for $scope.isChecked variable. Angular will evaluate as false, unless you want to force to be created as true. And it's always a good idea to avoid $watch expressions, especially in large scale apps or when you have options to do without using $watch. =)

Comment: Correct. I just put that in there to demonstrate how you could initially set the value of the checkbox.